# Scala: How to write a f function inside the currying function?

Tags: scala, currying

This sum function working fine, but I am having trouble to write the version that swap x and f:(Int=>Int)

**Works fine:**

```
def sum(f:Int=>Int):Int=>Int = {
    def ret_fun(x:Int):Int =
        if (x==1) f(1)
        else f(x)+ret_fun(x-1)
    ret_fun
}
```

**Did not work:**

```
def sum(x:Int):Int=>Int = {
    def ret_fun(f:Int=>Int):Int =
        if (x==1) f(1)
        else f(x)+ret_fun(x-1)
    ret_fun
}
```

Did anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: Did not work in what sense? Didn't compile, returned wrong answer?

Comment: Your ret_fun expects function, you are trying to pass it an Int.

Comment: To make @YaroslavFyodorov comment a bit more explicit: in the fourth line in the second example, you should have `else f(x) + ret_fun(f)` instead of `else f(x) + ret_fun(x-1)`, because the argument to `ret_fun` must be the function `f`, not the integer `x`.

Comment: @Tobias Then it will loop forever? `ret_fun(f)` calling `ret_fun(f)`. I am not sure what the second piece of code is supposed to do anyway

Comment: @YaroslavFyodorov Did not compile, the compiler gave me errors. I don't know how to fix this

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the return type of the second `sum` should be `(Int => Int) => Int`, because it's supposed to return a function that accepts an `Int => Int`  function, not an `Int` number.

Unfortunately you can't iterate over `x` using recursion of `ret_fun`, because `x` is not its argument. However you could use an indirect recursion of `sum`

```
def sum(x: Int): (Int => Int) => Int = {
  def ret_fun(f: Int => Int): Int =
    if (x == 1) f(1)
    else f(x) + sum(x - 1)(f)
  ret_fun
}
```

I imagine it may defeat the purpose of your exercise, because it's essentially the same as saying:

```
def sum(x: Int)(f: Int => Int): Int =
  if (x == 1) f(1)
  else f(x) + sum(x - 1)(f)
```

If your idea was to implement `ret_fun` using direct recursion and achieve the full analogy with the first example, let me comment on why it's problematic.

The reason is that the stop condition `x == 1` is defined in terms of `x` and not in terms of `f(x)`, so it's hard to determine which invocation should recurse and which shouldn't without changing the logic of the algorithm

```
def sum(x: Int): (Int => Int) => Int = {
  def ret_fun(f: Int => Int): Int =
    if (???) f(1)
    else f(x) + ret_fun(x => f(x - 1))
  ret_fun
}
```

We can, for instance, try `if (f(x) == 0) 0`, but as I said it will pretty much break the algorithm and will calculate `f(x) + f(x - 1) + ... + 0` instead of `f(x) + f(x - 1) + ... + f(1)`

Answer (score 0):

If you are fine with your second function depending on the first one, you just define it as this:

```
def sum(x: Int): (Int=>Int) => Int = f => sum(f)(x)
```

Otherwise you can do this:

```
def sum(x: Int): (Int => Int) => Int = f => f(x) + (if (x == 1) 0 else sum(x - 1)(f))
```

There's no need to define `ret_fun` separately.

If you absolutely want `ret_fun`, though, you can add `x` as a parameter to `ret_fun`, like this:

```
def sum(x: Int): (Int => Int) => Int = {
  def ret_fun(x: Int)(f: Int => Int): Int =
    if (x == 1) f(1)
    else f(x) + ret_fun(x - 1)(f)
  ret_fun(x)
}
```

If you want the function to be the first parameter, then you can do this, which is basically the same:

```
def sum(x: Int): (Int => Int) => Int = {
  def ret_fun(f: Int => Int)(x: Int): Int =
    if (x == 1) f(1)
    else f(x) + ret_fun(f)(x - 1)
  ret_fun(_)(x)
}
```